# jQuery mobile range slider with minimum range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In my project I have a requirement of range slider,which is having a minimum range, means the difference between the handle values should not go below a certain limit. So far I have tried the following, but it is not working.

## In HTML

```
<div data-role="rangeslider">                              
   <input name="departureStartRange" id="departureStartRange" min="0" max="24" value="11" type="range" />                              
   <input name="departureEndRange" id="departureEndRange" min="0" max="24" value="21" type="range" />
</div>
```

## In JS

```
var MIN_RANGE = 4;
$("#departureStartRange, #departureEndRange").on("change", function(e){ 
    var vala = parseInt($("#departureStartRange").val());
    var valb = parseInt($("#departureEndRange").val());
    var id=$(this).attr("id"),thisVal = parseInt($("#"+id).val()),newVal = (id == "departureStartRange") ? thisVal -1 : thisVal + 1;
    if((valb-vala) < MIN_RANGE){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#"+id).val(newVal).slider('refresh');
        return false;
    }
    $(".departureRange").text($("#departureStartRange").val()+" hrs - "+$("#departureEndRange").val()+" hrs")    
})
```

This code prevents the slider value change, but the handle still moves when we drag. Any help will be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can improve on your code, however if you drag one thumb over the other it ignores the change event for some reason:

```
<div id="theRangeSlider" data-role="rangeslider">
    <input name="departureStartRange" id="departureStartRange" min="0" max="24" value="11" type="range" />
    <input name="departureEndRange" id="departureEndRange" min="0" max="24" value="21" type="range" />
</div>

var MIN_RANGE = 4;
$("#departureStartRange, #departureEndRange").on("change", function (e) {
    var vala = parseInt($("#departureStartRange").val());
    var valb = parseInt($("#departureEndRange").val());
    var id = $(this).prop("id");        

    if ((valb - vala) < MIN_RANGE) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newVal = vala + MIN_RANGE;
        if (id == "departureStartRange") {
            newVal = valb - MIN_RANGE;
        }

        $(this).val(newVal);
        $("#theRangeSlider").rangeslider("refresh");
        return false;
    }
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c81xbzme/1/)**

UPDATE: to handle the exception where dragging one slider over another ignores the change event we can use the **[slider stop event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/#event-stop)**:

```
$(document).on( "slidestop","#departureStartRange, #departureEndRange", function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).trigger("change");
} );
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c81xbzme/3/)**

Comment: Thanks for your effort and reply.I appreciate it. But as you mentioned it moves when I drag one thumb over the other.

Comment: @TinoMThomas, see my updated answer. We can use the slidestop event to catch when one thumb is dragged on top of the other.

Comment: @ ezanker Thanks again, but still the handle moves. In jQuery ui we can achieve this functionality using 'slide' events, it is a bit annoying that jQuery doesn't enabled this event in its mobile version.